# How to get owner and locked object from locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0 event in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, locking, extended-events

I am capturing `locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0` events using Extended Events in SQL Server. The event session is following:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION MyQuery ON SERVER
    ADD EVENT sqlserver.locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0
    (
        ACTION (sqlserver.sql_text, sqlserver.tsql_stack)
    )
    ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer (SET max_memory = 4096)
    WITH (max_dispatch_latency = 1 seconds)
```

How can I determine what object is locked and who is currently locking it?

**UPDATE**: I need this for SQL Server 2008. How to debug lock timeouts on pre-2012 versions?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the information you want is not captured by this event.

You can see what fields are available for an event with:

```
select p.name package_name, o.name event_name, c.name event_field, c.type_name field_type, c.column_type column_type
from sys.dm_xe_objects o
join sys.dm_xe_packages p
      on o.package_guid = p.guid
join sys.dm_xe_object_columns c
      on o.name = c.object_name
where o.object_type = 'event'
  AND o.name = 'locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0'
order by package_name, event_name
```

the result is:

```
sqlserver   locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0  ID  uint16  readonly
sqlserver   locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0  UUID    guid_ptr    readonly
sqlserver   locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0  VERSION uint8   readonly
sqlserver   locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0  CHANNEL etw_channel readonly
sqlserver   locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0  KEYWORD keyword_map readonly
sqlserver   locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0  count   uint64  data
sqlserver   locks_lock_timeouts_greater_than_0  lock_type   uint64  data
```

However, in SQL 2012 this event was replaced ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx ) by lock_timeout_greater_than_0 which has the following set of fields

```
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 UUID    guid_ptr    readonly
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 VERSION uint8   readonly
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 CHANNEL etw_channel readonly
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 KEYWORD keyword_map readonly
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 collect_resource_description    boolean customizable
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 collect_database_name   boolean customizable
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 resource_type   lock_resource_type  data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 mode    lock_mode   data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 owner_type  lock_owner_type data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 transaction_id  int64   data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 database_id uint32  data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 lockspace_workspace_id  ptr data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 lockspace_sub_id    uint32  data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 lockspace_nest_id   uint32  data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 resource_0  uint32  data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 resource_1  uint32  data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 resource_2  uint32  data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 object_id   int32   data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 associated_object_id    uint64  data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 duration    uint64  data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 resource_description    unicode_string  data
sqlserver   lock_timeout_greater_than_0 database_name   unicode_string  data
```

From this I was able to derive the database (database_id) and in my case table (variously in object_id, associated_object_id, resource_0) from their Ids.

I didn't see an obvious way to find who was locking the object from the data captured by this event.

**EDIT** - see [SQL Server Lock Timeout Exceeded Deleting Records in a Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572585/sql-server-lock-timeout-exceeded-deleting-records-in-a-loop) for an example of using sp_lock and sp_who2 to debug the cause of a lock timeout event.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the information about changes in SQL Server 2012. Unfortunately, I need this information on SQL Server 2008. Maybe, someone else will found an workaround for SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Why have you set a lock timeout, normally it will wait an unlimited amount of time if there is not a deadlock?

Comment: The application has a user interface.

Comment: Well, then I suggest from your application you trap the error and capture the information such as from sp_lock and sp_who2 to see what has locks at the point of failure. See link at the end of my post above. What did you set your lock timeout to?